# Группировка и сортировка результирующей DataFrame из двух таблиц

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

Есть две таблицы:

```
People (id, Name, Salary, Sex, Profession)
Cars (id, id_polyuda, Mark)
```

Надо создать таблицу минимальных и максимальных зарплат в зависимости от пола, профессии и количества машин у одного человека. Вот исходные данные:

```
 ID      Name   Profession     Salary             Sex
  1 SMITH      Author          40000              m
  2 JOHNSON    Bricklayer       4000              f
  3 WILLIAMS   Cleaner         41000              m
  4 JONES      Florist          4500              f
  5 BROWN      Librarian        3900              m

 ID  ID_person Model   Price
  0    5       LADA    100000
  1    2      Toyota   50000
  2    1      Toyota   600000
  3    3      Daewoo   65000
  4    4      Subaru   300000
```

Я пробовал так:

```
res = people.groupby("['salary'], sort = True", "['salary'], sort = False", ["Sex"], ["Profession"],)
```

А как посчитать машины из из таблицы `Cars` по `ID_Person`? К тому же не знаю как группировать.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе результирующий DataFrame, который вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: Для начала вам нужно объединить две таблицы в одну. Но вот вопрос - судя по второй таблице, у каждой вашей персоны по одной машине. Есть ли тогда смысл во второй таблице вообще?

Comment: Что то у вас описание таблиц явно не совпадает с примером данных. Поправте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы делал это так:

```
car_stats = (cars
             .groupby("ID_person")
             .agg(cars_count=("Price", "size"), total_price=("Price", "sum"))
             .rename_axis("ID")
             .reset_index())

res = (people
        .merge(car_stats, how="left")
        .fillna(0)
        .groupby(["Sex", "Profession", "cars_count"])
        .agg(
            min_salary=("Salary", "min"),
            max_salary=("Salary", "max")
        ))
```

---

```
In [38]: res
Out[38]:
                           min_salary  max_salary
Sex Profession cars_count
f   Bricklayer 1                 4000        4000
    Florist    1                 4500        4500
m   Author     1                40000       40000
    Cleaner    1                41000       41000
    Librarian  1                 3900        3900
```

PS в вопросе вы привели не очень удачный пример данных, т.к. у всех людей строго по одной машине. В своем ответе я исходил из того, что у одного человека может быть несколько машин или не быть машин вовсе.

Comment: Большое спасибо за замечание, да пример не очень удачный, не заметил этого.